# Are maximal compact subgroups determined by their connected component?

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a Hausdorff locally compact group with identity component $G^0$, and assume $G / G^0$ is finite. The connected group $G^0$ has a maximal compact subgroup $K^0$, which is connected ([Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140622/are-maximal-compact-subgroups-of-connected-groups-connected)).

It is not hard to see that $K^0$ is contained in a maximal compact subgroup $K$ of $G$. This is simply because when $(g_i)$ are coset representatives for $G/G_0$, then there is no $g_i$ and distinct $g, h \in G^0/K^0$ for which $g_i g$ and $g_ih$ lie in a compact subgroup together with $K^0$, because otherwise $g^{-1}h$ would lie in a compact subgroup of $G^0$ strictly containing $K^0$. So by choosing $K$ containing the maximal number of $g_i g$, we find a maximal compact $K \subset G$ containing $K^0$ and with $|K/K^0| \leq |G/G^0|$.

Is $K$ unique?

This is just out of curiosity. In the case of Lie groups, this would make it convenient to   speak of a unique maximal compact subgroup by referring only to its Lie algebra.

Observations:

- When $G$ is a Lie group, $K$ meets all components of $G$ (Hochschild, *The structure of Lie groups*, Chapter XV Theorem 3.1)
- $K^0$ is normal in $K$ and $K/K^0$ is naturally a subgroup of $G/G^0$.

Comment: Just a remark. By a theorem of Mostow, $K$ is unique up to conjugacy and $KG^0=G$.

Comment: Another remark: let $N$ be the normalizer of $K^0$ in $G$. Then the given uniqueness holds iff $K$ is normal in $N$, and also holds iff $K/K^0$ is normal in $N/K^0$. In particular, it holds when $N/K^0$ is abelian, and also when $K=N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of counterexamples. This is more or less the same question as "do the elements of finite order form a subgroup".

A counterexample is the subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ consisting of diagonal and anti-diagonal matrices. Then $K_0 = 1$. The anti-diagonal elements are all of order $2$ and every one of them generates a maximal compact subgroup $K$.

Comment: A remark: this Lie group is isomorphic to the group of isometries of the Euclidean line.