# G mod compact subgroup is trivial bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Let $ G $ be a lie group with finitely many connected components (for example the real points of any linear algebraic group). Then $ G $ deformation retracts onto it's maximal compact subgroup. Indeed, $ G $ is diffeomorphic to a cartesian product
$$
K \times F
$$
where $ K $ is a maximal compact and $ F $ is contractible. Suppose that $ K' $ is some closed subgroup of $ K $. Then is it true that the coset manifold $ G/K' $ is diffeomorphic to the cartesian product
$$
K/K' \times F ?
$$

The fact for lie groups with finitely many components follows from the fact for connected lie
groupshttps://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society/volume-55/issue-10/A-new-proof-of-E-Cartans-theorem-on-the-topology/bams/1183514165.full together with the fact that the maximal compact of of a lie group meets every connected component [Are maximal compact subgroups determined by their connected component?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195864/are-maximal-compact-subgroups-determined-by-their-connected-component)

Comment: I think you have to assume here that $G$ is semisimple with finite center.

Comment: @AndreasCap:  I wrote an answer which I think shows that you do *not* need $G$ to have any special properties.  But perhaps my answer is flawed somewhere?

Comment: @JasonDeVito : My doubts do not concern the actual question posed here but the initial statement that $G$ is differeomorphic to $K\times F$. The versions of this that I know depend on semisimplicity (via Cartan decompositions) and even there, there are problems with the center, say for the universal covering of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Oh yes sorry about that. The integers are a lie group which is not diffeomorphic to product of compact and contractible. I've edited my question to add that the Lie group must have finitely many connected components to admit such a decomposition.

Comment: @AndreasCap:  I'm much more familiar with compact Lie groups than non-compact, but according to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53080/homotopy-type-of-connected-lie-groups, it seems that $G$ being a connected (real) Lie group is sufficient to conclude $G$ is diffeomorphic to $K\times F$.  But thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is true.

Given $K'\subseteq K\subseteq G$, one gets a fiber bundle $K/K'\rightarrow G/K'\rightarrow G/K$ where the the first map is induced by inclusion $K\rightarrow G$ and the projection is the obvious one sending $gK'$ to $gK$.

Assuming the existence of this bundle for the moment, since $G/K\cong F$ is contractible, the bundle must be trivial, so it is diffeomorphic to a product $K/K'\times G/K$.  But $G/K\cong F$.

So, where does this fiber bundle come from?

Well, for starters, we have a principal $K$ bundle $K\rightarrow G\rightarrow G/K$ coming from, say, right multiplication of $K$ on $G$.  (More generally, given any proper free action of a Lie group $K$ on a manifold $M$, one gets a principal bundle $K\rightarrow M\rightarrow M/K$.)

Now, note that $K$ acts on $K/K'$ by left multiplication.  So, we can form the space $(G\times K/K')/K$ where $K$ acts by right/left multiplication on both factors:  $k\ast( g, hK') = (gk^{-1}, khK')$.  This action is free and proper, so the quotient $(G\times K/K')/K$ is a smooth manifold.  Moreover, the projection $\pi:(G\times K/K')/K \rightarrow G/K$ given by $\pi( [ g, hK]) = gK$ is a fiber bundle map with fiber $K/K'$.  The inclusion $K/K'\rightarrow (G\times K/K')/K$ is obtained by fixed a point of $G$ (say, the identity $e\in G$), and mapping $hK'$ to $[(e,hK')]$.  This is called the associated bundle construction.

So, we have a bundle $K/K'\rightarrow (G\times K/K')/K\rightarrow G/K$.  The last step is to identify $(G\times K/K')/K$ with $G/K'$ and check that the maps work like we think.

So, consider $f:(G\times K/K')/K\rightarrow G/K'$ defined by $f([g,hK'])  = g h K'\in G/K'$.  Let's show that $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

First note that $f$ is well defined:  for any $k\in K$, $f([gk^{-1}, khK']) =  gk^{-1}khK'= ghK' = f([g,hK']$.  Moreover, $f$ is obviously smooth.

On the other hand, we can simply write down an inverse:  $f^{-1}(gK') = [(g, eK')]$.

I'll leave it to you to verify that this is the inverse.

To finish, I'll just verify that with respect to this diffeomorphism, the projection $G/K'\rightarrow G/K$ is $gK'\mapsto gK$; I'll leave the case of the inclusion of a fiber to you.  The projection $G/K'\rightarrow G/K$ is, via transport of structure, really the composition $G/K'\xrightarrow{f^{-1}} (G\times K/K')/K\rightarrow G/K$.  For an element $gK'\in G/K'$, this is $$gK'\mapsto [(g,eK')] \mapsto g/K.$$

Comment: I think one is only guaranteed to have a diffeo $G\cong K\times F$ if $G$ is connected.  If so, then this should be added as an assumption to my answer.