# Cohomology of $G/T$ for complex reductive group $G$

Tags: algebraic-groups, de-rham-cohomology, reductive-groups

Okay, I will try this again, last time people didn't like how I asked it  :)

So let's say $G$ is a reductive complex algebraic group; it could be $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ if that makes you happy (and in fact that's my case of interest!)

Let $T$ be the maximal torus of $G$; if $G=GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, then you can take $T$ to be the subgroup of diagonal matrices if you are so inclined :)

I am currently running into the following rather simple question in the project am I working on:

$\textbf{Question:}$ What is the de Rham cohomology of $G/T$.

I simply haven't found a reference and I'm sure it's known, so I was hoping someone here could point me to the result and save me some time :)

One may notice that if $G$ was compact, then I believe that $G/T$ is identified with the full flag variety of the complexification of $G$ (studied by Bott and Samelson).

Also, it's perhaps noteworthy that the orbit of a generic semisimple element in the Lie algebra of $G$ is isomorphic to $G/T$.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: From my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4344552/g-mod-compact-subgroup-is-trivial-bundle/4344921#4344921 , at least when $G$ is connected, you have $G/T$ diffeomorphic to $K/T\times \mathbb{R}^n$ where $K$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $G$ and and $G$ is diffeomorphic to $K\times \mathbb{R}^n$.  This reduces your calculation to the case where $G$ is compact.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm realizing now after talking to a friend that we could also use the projection $G/T\to G/B$ and the Serre spectral sequence